# VSCode jsconfig.json not recognize window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React project I have this jsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "mapRoot": "./src",
    "target": "ES6",
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

But below code still produces an error

```
window.addEventListener(type, callback)
```

that says:

**[js] Property 'dispatchEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof window'.**

Comment: Can you log `console.log(window.dispatchEvent)`? It seems to me that it is overridden. Also, where do you use this event? I hope not in your config files ;)

Comment: The dispatchEvent is there on the window object and the app works as intended. But VSCode complains about them not being there, wherever I try, and for whatever object I refer to. It's got to be something purely related to VSCode and jsconfig.